# How can I count columns in phalcon volt?

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

I'm new to phalcon. I am retrieving data from the blog
    table with many ways but I think I'm doing same thing again and again like `datetime DESC`, `datetime DESC LIMIT 5`, `views DESC LIMIT 5`, etc. from the same table. Is there an easy way to retrieve data in one query?

I want to count comments in volt for each post. But it shows like: 11 instead of 2. How do I count comments?

```
 # Blog Controller
 public function indexAction()
 {
   #Data Retrieve
    $bloger = Blogs::find(["order" => "datetime DESC"]);
    $this->view->setVar('blogs', $bloger);
  :Count How Many Post have each User
    $pcount = Blogs::findBybauthor($this->session->get('uname'));
    $this->view->setVar('eachpost',count($pcount));
  :Get Recent Posts
    $latest = Blogs::find(["order" => "datetime DESC limit 5"]);
    $this->view->setVar('recent', $latest);
  :Get Most visited Posts
    $viewer = Blogs::find(["order" => "views DESC limit 5"]);
    $this->view->setVar('views', $viewer);
  :Comments Retrieve
    $coment = Comments::find();
    $this->view->setVar('comented', $coment);
    }

   #[VOLT]
```

This is my volt tags its not showing as expected. I also use |length but it's not working as expected:

```
 {% for coment in comented %}
 {% if coment.entry_id === bloger.id %}
 <?php echo(count($coment->entry_id)); ?>
 {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Thanx! moopet You are right edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In controller first try to render each posts detail  in view (blog/show)
Here is my controller.php.


public function showfullAction($pid)
{
    $blog = Blogs::findFirstById($pid);
    $gid = $blog->id;
    $data = Blogs::findFirstById($gid);
    $this->view->setVar('detail', $data);
    #Similar Posts
    $similar = Blogs::find(["btitle LIKE :title:","bind"=>["title"=>'%'.$data->btitle.'%'],"order" => "datetime DESC limit 5"]);

    $this->view->setVar('datas', $similar); 
    $this->view->pick('blog/show');
   }

   And finally in my view page (blog/show):

 {% for similar in datas %}
 {{link_to('blog/showfull/'~similar.id,similar.btitle,'class':'cats')}}  <br/>
 {% endfor %}
```

and now its working as expected!

Answer (score 2):

```
public function indexAction()
{

// Get latest posts 
$bloger = Blogs::find([
    "order" => "datetime DESC", 
    "limit" => 10,
    "cache" => ["lifetime" => 3600, "key" => "my-find-key"]
]);
$this->view->setVar('blogs', $bloger);

// count posts by author
$pcount = Blogs::count([
    "bauthor = :author:",
    "bind" => [
        "bauthor" => $this->session->get('uname')
    ]
]);
$this->view->setVar('eachpost', $pcount);
// Info about model aggregations here: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#generating-calculations

// latest posts (i would suggest you to cache those queries since they will not change frequenlty. More info in the link below)
$latest = Blogs::find([
    "order" => "datetime DESC", 
    "limit" => 5,
    "cache" => ["lifetime" => 3600, "key" => "my-find-key"]
]);
$this->view->setVar('recent', $latest);

// top views (i would suggest you to cache those queries since they will not change frequenlty. More info in the link below)
$viewer = Blogs::find([
    "order" => "views DESC", 
    "limit" => 5,
    "cache" => ["lifetime" => 3600, "key" => "my-find-key"]
]);
$this->view->setVar('views', $viewer);

// Get current post (if no other params are passed findFirst fetches records by table's Primary key)
$currentPost = Blogs::findFirst($postID);

// Get post comments (im not sure what you want to do here, but i guess you wnat to get comments for the current post only.)
$coment = Comments::find([
    "blog_id = :blog_id:",
    "bind" => [
        "blog_id" => $currentPost->id
    ]
]);
$this->view->setVar('comented', $coment);

// Another example using query build to fetch all posts and their comments count with one query
$this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
  ->columns(array('blogs.*', 'COUNT(comments.id) AS commentCount'))
  ->from(array('blogs' => 'Blogs'))
  ->leftJoin('Comments', 'comments.blog_id = blogs.id', 'comments')
  ->groupBy(array('Comments.blog_id'));    
  ->getQuery()->execute();
}
```

More info on working with Phalcon models: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html

Comment: I cant Count in to controller i need to count comments on each post. and i don't want to use query builder is it possible with simple query? and please could you tell me ho to retrieve similar posts with simple query?

Comment: You can read here how to rewrite query builder into model query: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_Criteria.html 

About similar posts: you can reuse latest posts query above and just add where clause for the similarity. I guess by similar you mean from same category?

Comment: no i don't mean it similar category i just mean it similar title. isn't it possible without query builder?

Comment: i follow your instruction but showing error like : PhalconException:: Service 'modelsCache' wasn't found in the dependency injection container. and im not using front or backend cache im using simple invo eaxmple.

Comment: You can skip the cache parameter, i just shared it so you know it exists and its awesome. If you want you can read more here: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models-cache.html You can find similar records by title with normal LIKE clause in your conditions. No need to use query builder, like: Blogs::find([
    "title LIKE :title:",
    "bind" => [
        "title" => '%'. $currentPost->title .'%'
    ]
])

More info here: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#finding-records

Comment: Sir, You are Great!! Thanx a lot. i solved my "comments count for each post" problem like this way:$counts =  $this->modelsManager->executeQuery("SELECT Comments.entry_id FROM Comments WHERE Comments.entry_id = $bloger->id");
echo(count($counts));

Comment: But i just trying to get similar post like this way: $similar = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery("SELECT Blogs.btitle FROM Blogs WHERE Blogs.btitle LIKE '$detail->btitle' LIMIT 5");
 echo($similar); But its showing error whats my fault? please!

Comment: Whats the error? Instead of echo use print_r. $similar should contain a resultset not only 1 string.
Perhaps its not error but empty result set? Try with: LIKE '%$detail->btitle%'

Comment: I use like: $similar = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery("SELECT Blogs.btitle FROM Blogs WHERE Blogs.btitle LIKE '% $detail->btitle %'");echo($similar); and the error shows like: Catchable fatal error:  Object of class Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\cache\volt\c__xampp_htdocs_demo_app_views_blog_show.volt.php. and print_r shows more error

Comment: Read my comment above. You can not use echo on object! Try with print_r($similar).

Comment: im typing it into volt. Its print like : Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple Object
(
    [_result:protected] => 
    [_cache:protected] => 
    [_isFresh:protected] => 1
    [_pointer:protected] => 0
    [_count:protected] => 0
    [_activeRow:protected] => 
    [_rows:protected] => Array
        (
        )
    [_row:protected] => 
    [_errorMessages:protected] => 
    [_hydrateMode:protected] => 0
    [_model:protected] => Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Row Object
        (
        )

    [_columnMap:protected] => Array
        (
            [btitle] => btitle
        )
    [_keepSnapshots:protected] =>

Comment: It means no records where found. I doubt there is other posts with title containing current post title... Please read more about php and basic programming. Also read Phalcon's documentation.

Comment: Really Bro! you are absolutely right! im trying to show from blog-post page to show-all page. it means in blog-post page have all posts and in show-all page rendering each individual posts in-detail. im trying to get similar post in show-all page like this(as your instruction:):

Comment: $similar = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery("SELECT Blogs.btitle FROM Blogs WHERE Blogs.btitle LIKE '%$detail->btitle%' LIMIT 5");
 print_r($similar); But not getting ecpected i also read more phalcon example but as your instruction is better then other. please help! i know you you waste more time for me. please save me